# Wacom tablet/pen with Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, wacom

I just acquired a Wacom Intuos CTL4100, and I'm trying to use pressure sensitivity with Illustrator's calligraphic brush tool. I've set the Size to Pressure, and the Variation to match the Size, but the lines always end up having no variation in width. I have the feeling that there must be some way to set the sensitivity on the pen itself, but online searches only take me to Photoshop fixes. Suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: I can't replicate this issue (Intuos PTL here though). I get [stroke variations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LyClG.gif), assuming [variations are set for the brush](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iVvLI.png). There are no "pen settings" to adjust specifically for this. It's all done in the brush for Illustrator - not in the stylus. I assume you've installed the latest Wacom Drivers and then rebooted the system.

Comment: Do you have the sensitivity on another applications away from Illustrator ?

Comment: Scott, when I set the parameters to the same ones you have in your sample, I get the same calligraphic effect that you do. But that's not what I'm looking for. I want a very simple, round brush, with only the size set to vary on pressure. I've followed what I've seen on online videos, and all I get is a line with no varying width. In Photoshop, it works exactly the way I want it to....nice varying width line, nice and intuitive. Like FreeHand!